# Arranging a list of AlphaNumberic string in c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, collections, alphanumeric

I have a list of alpha-numeric strings which are something like this:
`v1_2014`.

I have these values ranging from `v1` to `v53` from year `2014` to `2016`. I want to arrange them in this order `v1_2014` to `v53_2014` , `v1_2015` to `v53_2015` and so on.

When i try to sort the list the order returned is

```
v1_2014, v1_2015,v1_2016, v10_2014, v10_2015, ... ,v2_2014,v2_2015,v2_2016,v20_2014
```

and so on.

Can someone give me an idea on how to sort this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all you versions have a template like this "V{number}_{Year}" you can use this code

```
List<string> Versions = new List<string>();
// Fill Versions
Versions = Versions.OrderBy(V => Convert.ToInt32(V.Split('_')[1]))
        .ThenBy(V => Convert.ToInt32(V.Split('_')[0].Remove(0, 1)))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Arvin! Will try and get back to you.

Comment: I think `.ThenBy(V => V.Split('_')[0])` will sort V10 before V2 because it's alphabetic. I suspect Sunny wants 2 before 10.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement an own `IComparer<string>` like that:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<String>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        // your comparing logic            
    }
}
```

Then you can sort your list like that:

```
List<string> myStrings = // wherever you get them
myString.Sort(new MyComparer());
```

A possible implementation of `MyComparer.Compare` could look like this:

```
public int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    string[] xpart = x.Split('_');
    int x1 = int.Parse(xpart[0].Trim('v'));
    int x2 = int.Parse(xpart[1]);
    string[] ypart = y.Split('_');
    int y1 = int.Parse(ypart[0].Trim('v'));
    int y2 = int.Parse(ypart[1]);

    if (x2 < y2) return -1;
    if (x2 > y2) return 1;
    if (x1 < y1) return -1;
    if (x1 > y1) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

This is only a suggestion that surely can be improved. At first by some error handling if the strings are not always well formed.

The criteria for `Compare` are

- if `x` is smaller than `y` return `-1`
- if `x` is greater than `y` return 1
- if `x` equals `y` return 0

with "smaller", "greater" and "equal" according to your required sorting.

Comment: Hi René Vogt, Thanks! But i already tried that, using string the returned sorted order is 1 10 11 12 13 ....2 20 21 23 ...3 30 31 32. I am not able to figure out a way to sort the string to get the required order.

Comment: @SunnyB added a possible `Compare` implementation that should work.

Comment: Thanks! Will try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a LINQ query to order this, therefore you need to split the value and parse the tokens to `int`:

```
int version = 0, year = 0;
IEnumerable<string> orderedByYearAndVersion = values
    .Select(v => new { value = v, tokens = v.Split('_') })
    .Where(x => x.tokens.Length == 2
                && x.tokens[0].StartsWith("v")
                && int.TryParse(x.tokens[0].Substring(1), out version)
                && int.TryParse(x.tokens[1], out year))
    .Select(x => new { x.value, version, year })
    .OrderBy(x => x.year)
    .ThenBy(x => x.version)
    .Select(x => x.value);
```

But in general it's better to create a custom class with  properties like `int Year` and `int Version`. Then you could implement `IComparable` and methods like `List.Sort` work automatically.

Comment: Thanks @timschmelter